# C# Methods: Defined Parameter Default Value Issue

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, default-value, named

I am writing an app that requires the calculation of the Gamma function.
A code (part of a class) snippet is below:

```
namespace PB.Utilities.Math
{
// class definition
public class SpecialFunctions
{
    // Private Fields

    // Instance Constructor
    public SpecialFunctions() {}

    //  Public Method for Gamma Function
    //       x       = input value; x MUST BE > 0
    //       GammaLn = secondary output value equal to natural log of Gamma Function
    public double Gamma(double x, out double GammaLn)
    {
        try
        {
            if (x <= 0) throw new System.ArgumentException("arg <= 0 in GammaFunction", "x");
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("argument <= 0 in GammaFunction");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }

        double gammaln;
        double _gamma = gamma(x, out gammaln);
        GammaLn = gammaln;
        return _gamma;
    }

    //  private method for Gamma Function
    private double gamma(double xx, out double gammaln)
    {
        //  private constants
        int j;
        double x,tmp,y,ser;

        const double k1 = 5.24218750000000000;
        const double k2 = 0.999999999999997092;
        const double k3 = 2.5066282746310005;

        double[] cof = new double[14]
        {
            57.1562356658629235,     -59.5979603554754912,      14.1360979747417471,
            -0.491913816097620199,     0.339946499848118887e-4,  0.465236289270485756e-4,
            -0.983744753048795646e-4,  0.158088703224912494e-3, -0.210264441724104883e-3,
             0.217439618115212643e-3, -0.164318106536763890e-3,  0.844182239838527433e-4,
            -0.261908384015814087e-4,  0.368991826595316234e-5
        };

        y = x = xx;
        tmp = x + k1;
        tmp = (x + 0.5) * System.Math.Log(tmp) - tmp;
        ser = k2;
        for (j = 0; j < 14; j++) ser += cof[j]/++y;
        gammaln = tmp + System.Math.Log(k3*ser/x);
        return System.Math.Exp(gammaln);
    }
}
}

public class BSA
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create an object of type PB.Utilities.Math.SpecialFunctions
        PB.Utilities.Math.SpecialFunctions Function = new PB.Utilities.Math.SpecialFunctions();

    // Call the public method GammaFunction.
    double GammaLn1;
    double GammaLn2;
    double GammaLn3;
    double g1 = Function.Gamma(3.5, out GammaLn1);
    double g2 = Function.Gamma(1.5, out GammaLn2);
    double g3 = Function.Gamma(1/7, out GammaLn3);
    System.Console.WriteLine("g(7/2) = "+g1);
    System.Console.WriteLine("g(3/2) = "+g2);
    System.Console.WriteLine("g(1/7) = "+g3);
    }
}
```

The issue is that at compilation, the parameter x in Gamma (even though x is being assigned the value 3.5 in the calling component) is assigned a value of 0 which triggers the exception. Can anyone please suggest how I can get around this? Thank you.

Comment: As a side note you may want to throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` instead of `ArgumentException`.

Comment: have you tried forcing the constant to be used as a double? something like: `double g1 = Function.Gamma(3.5f, out GammaLn1);`

Comment: That error cannot occur at compilation, as you claim.

Comment: Is the function Gamma contained in the class Function?

Comment: Thank you re the Arg out of range exception. I will change that. Re the 3.5f, this does not work. The issue is the default value 0 assigned at compilation that forces the exception.

Comment: @Zeos6 What default value at compilation? Your function isn't getting called at compilation.

Comment: Yes Gamma is contained in a class called SpecialFunctions and Function is an instance. I disagree Icarus. The issue occurs at compilation but is not a compilation error. At compilation a default va;lue of 0 is assigned and when you execute the exception is thrown.

Comment: Do you have a class variable called "x" anywhere in SpecialFunctions? Try changing the name of 'x' in the function Gamma to something else like 'gammaValue' and see if you get the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be 3.5 in my test cases.  Are you sure you haven't excluded some information that might be the issue?

```
using System;

namespace Doubletesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double d = Doubletesting.TestDouble(3.5);

            Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static double TestDouble(double x)
        {
            double result;

            result = x;

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
3.5
```

**UPDATED**

The Error is caused by your `Function.Gamma(1 / 7, out GammaLn3)`.  This is because both 1 and 7 are `INT` and dividing (int)1 by (int)7 is zero.  Try `Function.Gamma(1f / 7f, out GammaLn3)`.

Comment: hmmm. The calling component is outside of the namespace but that shouldn't affect it. I would post more of the code but am not sure how to do it as part of the comment.

Comment: Normally you should update your original question with more information.  Don't use comments to extend your question or question information.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the code originally posted in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much Eric. That is indeed the issue. I have fixed this. Thanks very much for your help.